# Shortest program to split a string at non-digits without RegExps

Tags: code-golf, string, restricted-source

***EDIT: If you're using Lisp, I have given some guidelines at the bottom in counting bytes.***

**Objective:** Make the shortest function that splits a string at non-digits and returns an array consisting of only digits in each string, without the use of any regular expressions. Leading zeroes are to be included in each string.

### Current Standings (separated in categories):

- **C/C++/C#/Java:** 68 (C) ....
- **GolfScript/APL/J:** 13 (APL)
- **All others:** 17 (Bash, uses `tr`), 24 (Ruby)

### Rules:

- The format must be as a function with a single string argument. Up to two additional arguments may be added if necessary for the proper return of the array (e.g. sh/csh/DOS Batch needs an extra variable reference to return, etc.).
- The primary function declaration doesn't count, and nor does importing other standard libraries. `#include`s, `import`s, and `using`s don't count. Everything else does. This does include `#define`s and helper functions. Sorry for the confusion. Refer to this as a helpful guide as to what does/does not count (written in C-style syntax)

  ```
  // doesn't count toward total, may be omitted unless
  // non-obvious, like half of Java's standard library.
  #include &lt;stdio.h&gt;

  import some.builtin.Class // doesn't count, see above

  #define printf p // counts towards total

  /* Any other preprocessor directives, etc. count. */

  int i = 0; // counts

  someFunction(); // counts

  char[][] myMainSplitFunction(char[][] array) { // doesn't count
    // Everything in here counts
    return returnArray; // Even this counts.
  } // doesn't count

  /* Everything in here counts, including the declaration */
  char[][] someHelperFunction(char[] string) {
      // stuff
  } // even this counts
  ```
- The output must be a string array or similar (Array lists in Java and similar are acceptable). Examples of accepted output: `String[]`, `char[][]`, `Array<String>`, `List<String>`, and `Array` (object).
- The array must contain only contain variable-length string primitives or string objects. No empty strings should be present in the return, with the exception below. **Note:** the strings are to contain a string of consecutive matches, such as the example input and output below.
- If there are no matches, then the function body should return `null`, an empty array/list,  or an array/list containing an empty string.
- No external libraries allowed.
- DOS line endings count as one byte, not two (already covered in meta, but needs to be emphasized)
- **And the biggest rule here: no regular expressions allowed.**

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) question, so shortest code wins. Good luck!

And here are some example inputs and outputs (with C-style escapes):

```
Input:  "abc123def456"
Output: ["123", "456"]

Input:  "aitew034snk582:3c"
Output: ["034", "582", "3"]

Input:  "as5493tax54\\430-52@g9.fc"
Output: ["5493", "54", "430", "52", "9"]

Input:  "sasprs]tore\"re\\forz"
Output: null, [], [""], or similar
```

Please put how many bytes used by your answers, and as always, happy golfing!

---

### Guidelines for Lisp

Here's what does and doesn't count in Lisp dialects:

```
;;; Option 1
(defun extract-strings (a b) ; Doesn't count
(stuff) ;;; Everything in here counts
) ; Doesn't count
;;; Option 2
(defun extract-strings (string &aux (start 0) (end 0)) ; Doesn't count
(stuff) ;;; Everything in here counts
) ; Doesn't count.
```

All other lambdas fully count towards the byte count.

Comment: Wasn't this asked before?

Comment: Yes, but I re-asked it on Meta and made substantial edits to it before posting it again here. Because of this, it shouldn't be classified as a duplicate (the other related one should be closed if not already).

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel [It's been deleted.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/18455/9498 "deleted post; you need enough reputation to view this")

Comment: Shouldn't your "golf" be posted as an answer?

Comment: Sorry, but -1 for disallowing GolfScript. All languages should be allowed.

Comment: @Doorknob That's true, but I also understand the OP's feelings. People should have a chance to compete even if they don't speak GolfScript, J, or APL (and I'm guilty of perusing the latter in these competitions.) Can you give a look at [my proposal](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1076) in the thread he linked to?

Comment: I did edit the rules a little because I missed the other two (J i intentionally overlooked, but I forgot about APL). I am going to have two separate scoring levels for those three and any others.

Comment: Comment added by request of @maf-soft: the c# 66 solution was invalid: it returns all digits as char-array

Answer (score 10):

## APL, 13 chars

(or 28 / 30 bytes, read below)

```
{⍵⊂⍨⍵∊∊⍕¨⍳10}
```

I see you've banned GolfScript from your question. I understand your sentiment, but I hope this community won't eventually ban APL, because it's a truly remarkable programming language with a long history, not to mention a lot of fun to code in. Maybe it could just be scored differently, if people feel it's competing unfairly. I'll post my thoughts on this matter to that thread you've linked.

On that same token, I've always added a footnote to my APL posts, claiming that APL could be scored as 1 char = 1 byte. My claim rests on the fact that a few (mostly commercial) APL implementations still support their own legacy single-byte encoding, with the APL symbols mapped to the upper 128 byte values. But maybe this is too much of a stretch, in which case you may want to score this entry as 28 bytes in UTF-16 or 30 bytes in UTF-8.

**Explanation**

```
{        ⍳10}  make an array of naturals from 1 to 10
       ⍕¨      convert each number into a string
      ∊        concatenate the strings into one (it doesn't matter that there are two 1s)
    ⍵∊         test which chars from the argument are contained in the digit string
 ⍵⊂⍨           use it to perform a partitioned enclose, which splits the string as needed
```

**Examples**

```
      {⍵⊂⍨⍵∊∊⍕¨⍳10} 'ab5c0x'
 5  0 
      {⍵⊂⍨⍵∊∊⍕¨⍳10}  'z526ks4f.;8]\p'
 526  4  8
```

The default output format for an array of strings does not make it clear how many strings are there in the array, nor how many blanks. But a quick manipulation to add quotes should make it clear enough:

```
      {q,⍵,q←'"'}¨ {⍵⊂⍨⍵∊∊⍕¨⍳10} 'ab5c0x'
 "5"  "0" 
      {q,⍵,q←'"'}¨ {⍵⊂⍨⍵∊∊⍕¨⍳10}  'z526ks4f.;8]\p'
 "526"  "4"  "8"
```

Comment: Regarding your comment, I think that for other languages compete fairly with "shorthand" ones one should count each symbol in the other languages as one char. For example, my Mathematica solution posted here should be counted as 7 (more or less). Designing a language with compressed tokens is not merit at all, I think.

Comment: Could you provide a hex dump of your golf? I can't read some of the characters.

Comment: @impinball How would the hexdump help you? It's not like you would see what is being done.

Comment: @impinball the APL code is {omega enclose commute omega epsilon epsilon format each iota 10}. If you need the unicode values you can just copy and paste it to any [online tool](http://www.mobilefish.com/services/unicode_escape_sequence_converter/unicode_escape_sequence_converter.php), even if you can't see the characters (which is strange, as most modern Unicode fonts have the APL symbols) In any case what you get is this {\u2375\u2282\u2368\u2375\u220a\u220a\u2355\u00a8\u237310} (mind the last "10" which is not part of the escape sequence)

Comment: For some reason, it was not rendering on my Andriod with both Dolphin and Chrome, and on IE on this computer, the majority aren't rendering, either. But thank you, anyways.

Comment: I am changing the rules a bit to actually score them separately.

Comment: One of the less ⍨-ish APL solutions!

Comment: Before seeing your program I couldn't fully appreciate Dijkstra's quote about "APL [being] a mistake, carried through to perfection." ([link](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs655/readings/ewd498.html)). Thank you for an eye-opener ;-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You're welcome. I of course disagree with the mistake part. If you wish to peruse my posting history on this site, you'll find many APL posts, almost always followed by an explanation of the algorithm. [The most recent golf I won](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/21461) was with 4 chars, for an admittedly non-trivial question :-)

Comment: @Tobia OMG! After seeing your four-character winner I no longer sure that APL was a mistake - I am beginning to sense a malicious intent :) :) :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes, world domination. We're working on it. APL has been one of the preferred languages in the financial sector for many decades. DUM DUM DUM…

Comment: Instead of `∊⍕¨⍳10`, couldn't you just use `⎕D`? That should be the constant `'0123456789'`. Dyalog APL at the very least supports it, and so does NARS2000.

Comment: @marinus Yes I could. I didn't know it when I wrote this entry, thank you.

Comment: You should mention that this is only APL2 (or proper `⎕ML` for APL*PLUS/Dyalog APL), and so it doesn't work on [TryAPL.org](http://tryapl.org/?a=%7B%u2375%u2282%u2368%u2375%u220A%u220A%u2355%A8%u237310%7D%20%20%27z526ks4f.%3B8%5D%5Cp%27&run).

Answer (score 5):

### Python 47

**Implementation**

```python
f=lambda s:"".join([' ',e][e.isdigit()]for e in s).split()
```

**Demo**

```
>>> sample=["abc123def456","aitew034snk582:3c","as5493tax54\\430-52@g9.fc","sasprs]tore\"re\\forz"]
>>> [f(data) for data in sample]
[['123', '456'], ['034', '582', '3'], ['5493', '54', '430', '52', '9'], []]
```

**Algorithm**

*Convert each non-digit character to space and then split the resultant string. A simple and clear approach.*

**And a fun solution with itertools (71 characters)**

```python
f1=lambda s:[''.join(v)for k,v in __import__("itertools").groupby(s,key=str.isdigit)][::2]
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Ruby, 70

```ruby
f=->(s){s.chars.chunk{|c|c.to_i.to_s==c}.select{|e|e[0]}.transpose[1]}
```

[Online Version](https://ideone.com/JC3uH2) for testing

Since converting any non-digit character to an int returns 0 in Ruby (with to_i), converting every char to int and back to char is the non-regex way to check for a digit...

Comment: You can also do a ('0'..'9').member? for every char, but what you did is shorter already

Comment: You are definitely right - I should have said: "a" way ;)

Answer (score 4):

## Bash, <strike>21 bytes</strike> 17/21 bytes (improved by [DigitalTrauma](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11259/digitaltrauma))

Building a space-separated list with `tr`

```
function split() {
tr -c 0-9 \ <<E
$1
E
}
```

replaces any non digit by a space

### Usage

```
$ for N in $(split 'abc123def456'); do echo $N; done
123
456
```

### Edit

as pointed by the comments below, the code can be stripped down to 17 bytes:

```
function split() (tr -c 0-9 \ <<<$1)
```

and as the result is not stricly speaking a Bash array, the usage should be

```
a=(`split "abc123def456"`); echo ${a[@]}
```

and the extra ``` (``) ``` should be counted

Comment: Gah you beat me to it!  But why not use a here-string instead of a here-document?  Also you can save a newline at the end of the function content you use `(blah)` instead of `{blah;}`:   `split()(tr -c 0-9 \ <<<$1)`.  That way your function body is only 17 chars.

Comment: Your function returns a "space-separated list" instead of an array.  Certainly returning true arrays from bash function is awkward, but you could at least assign the result of your function to an array in your usage:  `a=($(split "12 3a bc123")); echo ${a[@]}`.  It could be argued that "($())" be counted in your score

Comment: Before exploring the `tr` approach, [I tried doing this with a parameter expansion](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21995/11259).  `tr` is definitely the better approach for golfing purposes.

Comment: Have you tried surrounding the `tr` with the expansion operator? It would come out to something like `($(tr...))`,  and where the function declaration doesn't count, the outer parentheses wouldn't count against you. It would only be the command substitution part.

Comment: I don't see how this should be working, but I'm not fluent in Bash arrays though. Anyway, the `(``)` construct is 1-char better than the `($())` one and shall be prefered.

Answer (score 4):

## bash, 26 (function contents: 22 + array assignment overhead 4)

This isn't going to beat [the other `bash` answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21990/11259), but its interesting because it might make you double-take:

```
f()(echo ${1//+([!0-9])/ })
```

Usage is:

```
$ a=(`f "ab5c0x"`); echo ${a[@]}
5 0
$ a=(`f "z526ks4f.;8]\p"`); echo ${a[@]}
526 4 8
$
```

At the first quick glance, `//+([!0-9])/`  looks a lot like a regexp substitution, but it isn't.  It is a [bash parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), which follows [pattern-matching rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html), instead of regular expression rules.

Returning true bash array types from bash functions is a pain, so I chose to return a space-delimited list instead, then convert to an array in an array assignment outside of the function call.  So in the interests of fairness, I feel the `` (` `) `` around the function call should be included in my score.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica 32

```
StringCases[#,DigitCharacter..]&
```

Usage

```
inps ={"abc123def456", "aitew034snk582:3c", "as5493tax54\\430-52@g9.fc", 
        "sasprs]tore\"re\\forz"}  
StringCases[#,DigitCharacter..]&/@inps

{{"123", "456"}, 
 {"034", "582", "3"}, 
 {"5493", "54", "430", "52", "9"}, 
 {}
}
```

The equivalent using regexes is much longer!:

```
StringCases[#, RegularExpression["[0-9]+"]] &
```

Comment: Mathematica sucks at regex.

Answer (score 2):

## Smalltalk (Smalltalk/X), 81

```
f := [:s|s asCollectionOfSubCollectionsSeparatedByAnyForWhich:[:ch|ch isDigit not]]
```

f value:'abc123def456'
-> OrderedCollection('123' '456')

f value:'aitew034snk582:3c'
-> OrderedCollection('034' '582' '3')

f value:'as5493tax54\430-52@g9.fc' 
-> OrderedCollection('5493' '54' '430' '52' '9')

f value:'sasprs]tore\"re\forz' 
-> OrderedCollection()

sigh - Smalltalk has a tendency to use veeeery long function names...

Comment: Is that a function name? o__O

Comment: @tobia Apparently...

Comment: `asCollectionOfSubCollectionsSeparatedByAnyForWhich` ಠ_ಠ This name is too long

Answer (score 2):

## C, 68 bytes (only the function's body)

```js
void split (char *s, char **a) {
int c=1;for(;*s;s++)if(isdigit(*s))c?*a++=s:0,c=0;else*s=0,c=1;*a=0;
}
```

The first argument is the input string, the second one is the output array, which is a NULL-terminated string array. Sufficient memory must be reserved for `a` before calling the function (worst case: `sizeof(char*)*((strlen(s)+1)/2)`).

The input string is modified by the function (every non-digit character is replaced by `'\0'`)

### Usage example

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void split (char *s, char **a) {
int c=1;for(;*s;s++)if(isdigit(*s))c?*a++=s:0,c=0;else*s=0,c=1;*a=0;
}   

void dump(char **t) {
    printf("[ ");for(;*t;t++)printf("%s ", *t);printf("]\n");
}   

int main() {
    char **r = malloc(1024);
    char test1[] = "abc123def456";
    char test2[] = "aitew034snk582:3c";
    char test3[] = "as5493tax54\\430-52@g9.fc";
    char test4[] = "sasprs]tore\"re\\forz";
    split(test1,r); 
    dump(r);
    split(test2,r); 
    dump(r);
    split(test3,r); 
    dump(r);
    split(test4,r); 
    dump(r);
    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
[ 123 456 ]
[ 034 582 3 ]
[ 5493 54 430 52 9 ]
[ ]
```

### Un-golfed version:

```cpp
void split (char *s, char **a) {
    int c=1; // boolean: the latest examined character is not a digit
    for(;*s;s++) {
        if(isdigit(*s)) {
            if(c) *a++ = s; // stores the address of the beginning of a digit sequence
            c=0;
        } else {
            *s=0; // NULL-terminate the digit sequence
            c=1;
        }   
    }   
    *a = 0; // NULL-terminate the result array
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 27 bytes

```
{x@.t@=t-!#t:&~^(,/$!10)?x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcndCsIgGIDha5lFbTCX82c0I/JCLLClIwYu9IOkqFu3dvCePO@E/ehzdvKdVAPqCLhYgdx8L2W9WxctqU7pk922ROY6tJTdrOOiQwdk7mCfhPHoJ7Gnkg2LRcF7BiYJrjVnBAuqxr5xy4smPkI8wxysRv@0m8MLVfkH)

- `(,/$!10)` generate "0123456789"
- `&~^(...)?x` identify indices of digits in the input (e.g. `"abc123def456"` => `3 4 5 9 10 11`)
- `.t@=t-!#t:` split the indices into groups of adjacent indices (e.g. `3 4 5 9 10 11` => `(3 4 5;9 10 11)`)
- `x@` index back into the original output and return (e.g. `x[(3 4 5;9 10 11)]` => `("123";"456")`)

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 53

**Edit:** on no matches, sub now returns list with empty string (instead of empty list) as required.

It also avoids splitting on single space character, as it triggers *'split on any white-space'* behavior, which probably violates the rules. I could use `/ /` delimiter, which would split on single space, but paradoxically it would *look* like using regexp pattern. I could use `unpack` at the cost of some extra characters and so get rid of `split` controversy altogether, but I think that, what I finish with, splitting on a literal character (other than space) is OK.

```perl
sub f{shift if(@_=split a,pop=~y/0-9/a/csr)[0]eq''and$#_;@_}
```

And, no, Perl's transliteration operator doesn't do regular expressions. I can unroll 0-9 range to `0123456789` if that's the problem.

Comment: As long as it doesn't use regular expressions, it's valid.

Comment: My Perl is not so strong. If I understand the code, you are replacing non-digits with a specific non-digit, then splitting on that chosen non-digit, then filtering out empty strings. Is this a correct reading?

Comment: @TimSeguine: Not exactly. Non-digits are replaced and squashed to a single character, splitting on which produces empty string if that delimiter happens to be at the beginning. It is then shifted away if list contains other entries.

Comment: Enpty list is okay.

Answer (score 1):

### VBScript, 190 (164 without function declaration)

```
Function f(i)
For x=1 To Len(i)
c=Mid(i,x,1)
If Not IsNumeric(c) Then
Mid(i,x,1)=" "
End If
Next
Do
l=Len(i)
i=Replace(i,"  "," ")
l=l-Len(i)
Loop Until l=0
f=Split(Trim(i)," ")
End Function
```

While not competitive at all, I'm surprised that VBScript comes out this short on this given how verbose it is (13 bytes for the CRs alone). It loops through the string, replacing any non-numeric characters with spaces, then reduces all the whitespace to single spaces, and then uses a space delimiter to divide it.

**Test cases**

```
Input: "ab5c0x"
Output: 5,0

Input: "z526ks4f.;8]\p"
Output: 526,4,8
```

Comment: DOS line endings count as one character as far as I've read on meta.

Comment: I suggested an edit for you.

Comment: The count already assumes Linux style 1 byte line endings. I get 190 characters by my count (just verified again).

Comment: Ok. I must have miscounted.

Answer (score 1):

### R, 81

```
f=function(x){
s=strsplit(x,"",T)[[1]]
i=s%in%0:9
split(s,c(0,cumsum(!!diff(i))))[c(i[1],!i[1])]
}
```

The function accepts a string and returns a list of strings.

Examples:

```
> f("abc123def456")
$`1`
[1] "1" "2" "3"

$`3`
[1] "4" "5" "6"
```

-

```
> f("aitew034snk582:3c")
$`1`
[1] "0" "3" "4"

$`3`
[1] "5" "8" "2"

$`5`
[1] "3"
```

-

```
> f("as5493tax54\\430-52@g9.fc")
$`1`
[1] "5" "4" "9" "3"

$`3`
[1] "5" "4"

$`5`
[1] "4" "3" "0"

$`7`
[1] "5" "2"

$`9`
[1] "9"
```

-

```
> f("sasprs]tore\"re\\forz")
$<NA>
NULL
```

Note: `$x` is the name of the list element.

Answer (score 1):

### Common Lisp (1 according to the letter;  ≈173 according to the spirit)

Here's a readable version.  The byte count is fairly high because of the long names in things like `digit-char-p` and `position-if` and `vector-push-extend`.

```
(defun extract-numeric-substrings (string &aux (start 0) (end 0) (result (make-array 0 :adjustable t :fill-pointer 0)))
  (loop 
     (unless (and end (setq start (position-if #'digit-char-p string :start end)))
       (return result))
     (setq end (position-if (complement #'digit-char-p) string :start (1+ start)))
     (vector-push-extend (subseq string start end) result)))
```

```
(extract-numeric-substrings "abc123def456")
#("123" "456")

(extract-numeric-substrings "aitew034snk582:3c")
#("034" "582" "3")

(extract-numeric-substrings "as5493tax54\\430-52@g9.fc")
#("5493" "54" "430" "52" "9")

(extract-numeric-substrings "sasprs]tore\"re\\forz")
#()
```

The concept of "function declaration" is sort of vague.  Here's a version that only has one byte (the character `x` in the function body); everything else is bundled in to the auxiliary variables of the function's lamba list (part of the function's declaration):

```
(defun extract-numeric-substrings (string 
                                   &aux (start 0) (end 0) 
                                   (result (make-array 0 :adjustable t :fill-pointer 0))
                                   (x (loop 
                                         (unless (and end (setq start (position-if #'digit-char-p string :start end)))
                                           (return result))
                                         (setq end (position-if (complement #'digit-char-p) string :start (1+ start)))
                                         (vector-push-extend (subseq string start end) result))))
  x)
```

The actual byte count will depend on how many of auxiliary declarations would have to be moved into the body for this to be deemed acceptable.  Some local function renaming would help, too (e.g., shorten `position-if` since it appears twice, use single letter variables, etc.).

This rendering of the program has 220 characters:

```
(LOOP(UNLESS(AND END(SETQ START(POSITION-IF #'DIGIT-CHAR-P STRING :START END)))(RETURN RESULT))(SETQ END(POSITION-IF(COMPLEMENT #'DIGIT-CHAR-P)STRING :START(1+ START)))(VECTOR-PUSH-EXTEND(SUBSEQ STRING START END)RESULT))
```

If nothing else, this should promote [Common Lisp's &aux variables](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_dae.htm).

This can be written more concisely with `loop`, of course:

```
(defun extract-numeric-substrings (s &aux (b 0) (e 0) (r (make-array 0 :fill-pointer 0)))
  (loop 
     with d = #'digit-char-p 
     while (and e (setq b (position-if d s :start e)))
     finally (return r)
     do 
       (setq e (position-if-not d s :start (1+ b)))
       (vector-push-extend (subseq s b e) r)))
```

The `loop` form, with extra space removed, has 173 characters:

```
(LOOP WITH D = #'DIGIT-CHAR-P WHILE(AND E(SETQ B(POSITION-IF D S :START E)))FINALLY(RETURN R)DO(SETQ E(POSITION-IF-NOT D S :START(1+ B)))(VECTOR-PUSH-EXTEND(SUBSEQ S B E)R))
```

Comment: I would count starting from `(result` on to the final parenthesis to be the body. The part that defines the name and parameters are the declaration.

Comment: Please refer to rule 2 on my amended rules to see what I'm really talking about in a function declaration (basically, declare function name, parameters, and if syntactically required, which is rare among interpreted languages, the return type).

Comment: @impinball Yeah, the "1" count is sort of a joke, but the important part here is that `result` _is_ declared as a parameter here;  it just has a very non-trivial initialization form.  It's the same thing, in principle, as an optional argument with a default value that's computed by some complex expression.  (In simpler cases, it's easy to imagine something like `char* substring( char *str, int begin, int end(0) )` in some language with a C-like syntax to specify that `end` is optional and that if it's not provided, then its value is `0`.  I'm just highlighting the fact that some of these terms

Comment: @impinball aren't quite concrete and language agnostic enough to prevent some trollish byte counts. :)

Comment: The first part that isn't specifying parameters is where I would stat counting (e.g. `(defun fn (string &aux (start 0) (end 0)` wouldn't count, but everything remaining in the lambda would).

Comment: @impinball Everything in the lambda list after `&aux` is an auxiliary parameter.  The value for `start` is `0`, the value for `end` is `0`, the value for `result` is `(make-array ...)`, and the value for `x` is `(loop ...)`.  They're all in the lambda list of the function; the newlines aren't significant here (except as whitespace).  When parameter default values accept arbitrarily complex initialization forms, it becomes problematic to allow exclusion of parameter lists from byte count.

Comment: @impinball Even with all that bit about the &aux variables, though, I've posted a more direct version with `loop` that has a more "according to the spirit" byte count.

Answer (score 0):

**php**, **204**

```php
function s($x){$a=str_split($x);$c=-1;$o=array();
for($i= 0;$i<count($a);$i++){if(ord($a[$i])>=48&&ord($a[$i])<=57)
{$c++;$o[$c]=array();}while(ord($a[$i])>=48&&ord($a[$i])<=57)
{array_push($o[$c],$a[$i]);$i++;}}return $o;}
```

**Descriptive Code:**

```php
function splitdigits($input){

    $arr = str_split($input);
    $count = -1;
    $output = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){


    if(ord($arr[$i]) >= 48 && ord($arr[$i]) <= 57){
        $count++;
        $output[$count] = array();
    }

    while(ord($arr[$i]) >= 48 && ord($arr[$i]) <= 57){
        array_push($output[$count], $arr[$i]);
        $i++;
    } 

}

return $output;
}
```

This is pretty long code and I'm sure there will be a much shorter php version for this code golf. This is what I could come up with in php.

Comment: there are some improvements: you can replace `array()` with `[]`, `array_push($output[$count], $arr[$i]);` with `$output[$count][]=$arr[$i];`, and the `ord()` checks with `is_numeric()`. and you don't even need to split the string to iterate over its characters. also, only the inner code of the function counts, so as it is you char count is 204.

Comment: The function declaration doesn't count. Refer to rule 2 as a guide on what counts and what doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

## C, 158

```c
#define p printf
char s[100],c;int z,i;int main(){while(c=getchar())s[z++]=(c>47&&c<58)*c;p("[");for(;i<z;i++)if(s[i]){p("\"");while(s[i])p("%c",s[i++]);p("\",");}p("]");}
```

Since C doesnt have array print functions built-in I had to do that work on my own so I apologive that there is a final comma in every output. Essentially what that code does is it reads the string if it is not a digit it replaces it with '\0' and then I just loop through the code and print out all of the chains of digits.(EOF=0)

> Input: ab5c0x
>
> Output: ["5","0",]
>
> Input: z526ks4f.;8]\p
>
> Output: ["526","4","8",]

Comment: According to the question's rules (rule 2), you only have to count the characters in the function body. So your solution would actually be less than 170 bytes. I'm not sure if the count includes variable prototypes outside the function body, though.

Comment: I will amend the rules on this: `#define`s, variable declarations, etc. will count, but the function declaration will not.

Comment: Also, last time I checked, there was a type in C notated as `char[][]` which is legal. If you return as that (or `char**`), you will be fine.

Comment: It doesn't have To be text output? I though the program was supposed to output the array in a string format

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 98

```
static string[] SplitAtNonDigits(string s)
{
    return new string(s.Select(c=>47<c&c<58?c:',').ToArray()).Split(new[]{','},(StringSplitOptions)1);
}
```

First, this uses the LINQ `.Select()` extension method to turn all non-digits into commas. `string.Replace()` would be preferable, since it returns a `string` rather than a `IEnumerable<char>`, but `string.Replace()` can only take a single char or string and can't make use of a predicate like `char.IsDigit()` or `47<c&c<58`.

As mentioned, `.Select()` applied to a string returns an `IEnumerable<char>`, so we need to turn it back into a string by turning it into an array and passing the array into the `string` constructor.

Finally, we split the string at commas using `string.Split()`. `(StringSplitOptions)1` is a shorter way of saying `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`, which will automatically takes care of multiple consecutive commas and commas at the start/end of the string.

Comment: Instead of `char.IsDigit(c)`, you can use `'/'<c&&c<':'`

Comment: Good point...or even better, `47<c&&c<58`. (Frankly, I'm surprised it works with numbers, but apparently it does).

Comment: And I can save an extra valuable character by using a single '&' instead of a double '&&'. In C#, this still logical AND when both operands are booleans -- it only does a bitwise AND when they're integers.

Comment: Nice one. I didn't know it was able to do that.

Comment: A slightly shorter variant is to split on white space instead of `,`, and then manually remove the empty items `return new string(s.Select(c=>47<c&c<58?c:' ').ToArray()).Split().Where(a=>a!="").ToArray();`

Answer (score 0):

### Python <s>104</s> 83

```
def f(s, o=[], c=""):
    for i in s:
        try:int(i);c+=i
        except:o+=[c];c=""
    return [i for i in o+[c] if i]
```

@Abhijit answer is far clever, this is just a "minified" version of what i had in mind.

```
assert f("abc123def456") == ["123", "456"]
assert f("aitew034snk582:3c") == ["034", "582", "3"]
assert f("as5493tax54\\430-52@g9.fc") == ["5493", "54", "430", "52", "9"]
assert f("sasprs]tore\"re\\forz") == []
```

This yields no output, so the code is working, if ran one by one, as some variables are defined at the declaration.

Comment: You don't have to count the function declaration, if you did. Just as a heads up

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 240 bytes

And for those of you who are curious, here's my probably huge golf:

```javascript
function split(a) { // begin function
function f(c){for(var a=-1,d=9;d--;){var e=c.indexOf(d+"");0
>e||e<a&&(a=e)}return 0<a?a:null}var c=f(a);if(null==c)retur
n null;var d=[];for(i=0;;){a=a.substring(c);d[i]||(d[i]="");
c=f(a);if(null==c)break;d[i]+=a.charAt(c);0<c&&i++}return d;
} // end function
```

#### Above in pretty print:

```javascript
function split(a) {
    function f(c) {
        for (var a = -1, d = 9;d--;) {
            var e = c.indexOf(d + "");
            0 > e || e < a && (a = e);
        }
        return 0 < a ? a : null;
    }
    var c = f(a);
    if (null == c) return null;
    var d = [];
    for (i = 0;;) {
        a = a.substring(c);
        d[i] || (d[i] = "");
        c = f(a);
        if (null == c) break;
        d[i] += a.charAt(c);
        0 < c && i++;
    }
    return d;
}
```

#### Above in normal descriptive code

```javascript
function split(a) {
    function findLoop(string) {
        var lowest = -1;
        var i = 9;
        while (i--) {
            var index = string.indexOf(i + '');
            if (index < 0) continue;
            if (index < lowest) lowest = index;
        }
        return (lowest > 0) ? lowest : null;
    }
    var index = findLoop(a);
    if (index == null) return null;
    var ret = [];
    i = 0;
    for ( ; ; ) {
        a = a.substring(index);
        if (!ret[i]) ret[i] = '';
        index = findLoop(a);
        if (index == null) break;
        ret[i] += a.charAt(index);
        if (index > 0) i++;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### PHP 134

```
function f($a){
$i=0;while($i<strlen($a)){!is_numeric($a[$i])&&$a[$i]='-';$i++;}return array_filter(explode('-',$a),function($v){return!empty($v);});
}
```

Comment: You can shorten it by leaving out the callback at `array_filter`. This will automatically remove all entries which are `false` when they're casted to booleans.

Comment: @kelunik that would filter out 0s as well

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 24

```
f=->s{s.tr("
-/:-~",' ').split}
```

Defines digits using negative space within the printable ascii range.

Comment: Function declaration doesn't count.

Answer (score 0):

**JS/Node : <strike>168</strike> <strike>162</strike> <strike>147</strike> 138 Chars**

```
function n(s){
var r=[];s.split('').reduce(function(p,c){if(!isNaN(parseInt(c))){if(p)r.push([]);r[r.length-1].push(c);return 0;}return 1;},1);return r;
}
```

Beautified version:

```
function n(s) {
  var r = [];
  s.split('').reduce(function (p, c) {
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(c))) {
      if (p) {
        r.push([]);
      }
      r[r.length - 1].push(c);
      return 0;
    }
    return 1;
  }, 1);
  return r;
}
```

Comment: This question only wants the array returned, so you can remove `console.log(r)` and some other things

Comment: The function declaration doesn't count toward the score (reason is to help level the playing field)

Comment: Ok. Adjusted the score as per @impinball's comment. (Actually there are two functions declared here. Char count includes the anonymous function)

Comment: It should. I updated the rules to help explain it better.

Comment: Meanwhile, came up with something better...

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, <strike>104</strike> <strike>97</strike> 89

*Golfed:*

**Edit:** When the loops walks off the end of the array, `c` is `undefined`, which is falsy and terminates the loop.

**2/27:** Using `?:` saves the wordiness of `if/else`.

```
function nums(s) {
s+=l='length';r=[''];for(k=i=0;c=s[i];i++)r[k]+=+c+1?c:r[k+=!!r[k][l]]='';
r[l]--;return r
}
```

The carriage return in the body is for readability and is not part of the solution.

*Ungolfed:*

The idea is to append each character to the last entry in the array if it is a digit and to ensure the last array entry is a string otherwise.

```
function nums(s) {
    var i, e, r, c, k;
    k = 0;
    s+='x'; // ensure the input does not end with a digit
    r=[''];
    for (i=0;i<s.length;i++) {
        c=s[i];
        if (+c+1) { // if the current character is a digit, append it to the last entry
            r[k] += c;
        }
        else { // otherwise, add a new entry if the last entry is not blank
            k+=!!r[k].length;
            r[k] = '';
        }
    }
    r.length--; // strip the last entry, known to be blank
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### PHP <s>98</s> 89

As in DigitalTrauma's bash answer, this doesn't use a regex.

```
function f($x) {
// Only the following line counts:
for($h=$i=0;sscanf(substr("a$x",$h+=$i),"%[^0-9]%[0-9]%n",$j,$s,$i)>1;)$a[]=$s;return@$a;
}
```

Test cases:

```
php > echo json_encode(f("abc123def456")), "\n";
["123","456"]
php > echo json_encode(f("aitew034snk582:3c")), "\n";
["034","582","3"]
php > echo json_encode(f("as5493tax54\\430-52@g9.fc")), "\n";
["5493","54","430","52","9"]
php > echo json_encode(f("sasprs]tore\"re\\forz")), "\n";
null
```

Answer (score 0):

**Python**

```
def find_digits(_input_):
    a,b = [], ""
    for i in list(_input_):
        if i.isdigit(): b += i
        else:
            if b != "": a.append(b)
            b = ""
    if b != "": a.append(b)
    return a
```

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell 31

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.Char (isDigit)
import Data.Text (split)

f=filter(/="").split(not.isDigit)
```

It splits the string on all non-numeric characters and removes the empty strings generated by consecutive delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 72

```
function f(a){
 a+=".",b="",c=[];for(i in a)b=+a[i]+1?b+a[i]:b?(c.push(b),""):b;return c
}
```

Ungolfed

```
a+=".",b="",c=[];        //add '.' to input so we dont have to check if it ends in a digit
for(i in a)
    b=+a[i]+1?           //check if digit, add to string if it is
        b+a[i]:         
    b?                   //if it wasnt a digit and b contains digits push it
        (c.push(b),""):  //into the array c and clear b
    b;                   //else give me b back
return c
```

Sample input/output

```
console.log(f("abc123def456"));
console.log(f("aitew034snk582:3c"));
console.log(f("as5493tax54\\430-52@g9.fc"));
console.log(f("sasprs]tore\"re\\forz"));

["123", "456"]
["034", "582", "3"]
["5493", "54", "430", "52", "9"]
[]
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dschu012/age5H/)**

Comment: I like it! Much simpler than my own. You can drop another 8 characters by replacing `if(+a[i]+1)b+=a[i];else if(b)c.push(b),b=""` with `b=+a[i]+1?b+a[i]:b?(c.push(b),""):b`.

Comment: @DocMax thx, I edited to include your suggestion :). That `(c.push(b),"")` seemed clever, never seen that.

Comment: I had forgotten about it until I saw it used extensively earlier today in http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22268#22279

Comment: That's not valid, ' ' is mistaken for 0 and it's a javascript quirk difficult to manage. Try '12 34 56'

Answer (score 0):

### VBA 210, 181 without function declaration

```
Function t(s)
Dim o()
For Each c In Split(StrConv(s,64),Chr(0))
d=IsNumeric(c)
If b And d Then
n=n&c
ElseIf d Then:ReDim Preserve o(l):b=1:n=c
ElseIf b Then:b=0:o(l)=n:l=l+1:End If:Next:t=o
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

## Rebol (66 chars)

```
remove-each n s: split s complement charset"0123456789"[empty? n]s
```

Ungolfed and wrapped in function declaration:

```
f: func [s] [
    remove-each n s: split s complement charset "0123456789" [empty? n]
    s
]
```

Example code in Rebol console:

```
>> f "abc123def456"
== ["123" "456"]

>> f "aitew035snk582:3c"
== ["035" "582" "3"]

>> f "as5493tax54\\430-52@g9.fc"
== ["5493" "54" "430" "52" "9"]

>> f {sasprs]torer"re\\forz}
== []
```

Answer (score 0):

### R 52

This function splits strings by character class (this is not regex! :)) class is N - numeric characters and P{N} means negation of this class. o=T means omit empty substrings.

```
x
## [1] "wNEKbS0q7hAXRVCF6I4S" "DpqW50YfaDMURB8micYd" "gwSuYstMGi8H7gDAoHJu"
require(stringi)
stri_split_charclass(x,"\\P{N}",o=T)
## [[1]]
## [1] "0" "7" "6" "4"

## [[2]]
## [1] "50" "8" 

## [[3]]
## [1] "8" "7"
```

Answer (score 0):

### PHP 99

```
<?php

$a = function($s) {
foreach(str_split($s)as$c)$b[]=is_numeric($c)?$c:".";return array_filter(explode('.',implode($b)));
};

var_dump($a("abc123def456"));
var_dump($a("aitew034snk582:3c"));
var_dump($a("as5493tax54\\430-52@g9.fc"));
var_dump($a("sasprs]tore\"re\\forz"));
```

#### Output

```
array(2) {
  [3]=>
  string(3) "123"
  [6]=>
  string(3) "456"
}
array(3) {
  [5]=>
  string(3) "034"
  [8]=>
  string(3) "582"
  [9]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
array(5) {
  [2]=>
  string(4) "5493"
  [5]=>
  string(2) "54"
  [6]=>
  string(3) "430"
  [7]=>
  string(2) "52"
  [9]=>
  string(1) "9"
}
array(0) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript 88

88 chars when not counting function n(x){}

```
function n(x){
y=[],i=0,z=t=''
while(z=x[i++])t=!isNaN(z)?t+z:t&&y.push(t)?'':t
if(t)y.push(t)
return y
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Racket 149

Golfed (according to the rules, only the length of the second line counts)

```
(define (extract-numeric-substrings s)
(let L([x(map string->number(string-split s""))])(set! x(dropf x false?))(if(null? x)x(let-values([(h t)(splitf-at x number?)])(cons(apply ~a h)(L t)
)))))
```

Ungolfed

```
(define (extract-numeric-substrings s)
  (let L ([x (map string->number (string-split s ""))])
    (set! x (dropf x false?))
    (if (null? x)
        x
        (let-values([(h t) (splitf-at x number?)])
          (cons (apply ~a h) (L t))))))
```

Results

```
(map extract-numeric-substrings '("abc123def456" 
"aitew034snk582:3c" 
"as5493tax54\\430-52@g9.fc" 
"sasprs]tore\"re\\forz"))

'(("123" "456")
("034" "582" "3")
("5493" "54" "430" "52" "9")
())
```

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript with lambdas, 84

```
extract=s=>[].reduce.call(s,(r,c)=>r+=(c!=+c?r[r.length-1]==" "?"":" ":c),"").trim().split(" ")
```

Tested in Firefox 27

Answer (score 0):

### VB.NET, 87

```
Imports System.Console
Imports System.String
Imports System.Char
Imports System.StringSplitOptions

Module All
  Public Function Parse(S As String) As String()
    Return Join("",From C In S Select If(IsDigit(C),C," ")).Split({" "},RemoveEmptyEntries)
  End Function

  Public Sub Main()
    For Each S As String In {"abc123def456", "aitew034snk582:3c", "as5493tax54\\430-52@g9.fc", "sasprs]tore\""re\\forz"}
      WriteLine(Join(":", Parse(S)))
    Next S
  End Sub
End Module
```

According the rules, only content of parse function is calculated:

```
Return Join("",From C In S Select If(IsDigit(C),C," ")).Split({" "},RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell 37

I am not counting the imports towards the bytecount, as per the scoring rules. The body of the code is a 1 liner (with semicolons, so there is actually no advantage other than looking more golfed), though I am not sure what to count and what not to count in the function definitions. This was originally longer, but I got inspiration from Coaumdio's and DigitalTrauma's `bash` solutions.

```
import Data.Char {-Not counted-}
i x|isDigit x=x;i _=' ';f=words.map i {-Fully Counted-}
```

`i` preserves digit characters, and replaces all other characters with space. `f` just maps `i` onto a string and then applies `words`, which splits a string into a list of substrings that were separated by arbitrarily long runs of whitespace. If I am missing any of the rules whereby I can reduce my bytecount by omitting certain characters from the score, I would appreciate comments to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

**APL: 22**

```
{(a/1,2</a)⊂⍵/⍨a←⍵∊⎕D}
```

**Explanation:**

```
a←⍵∊⎕D creates boolean of argument (⍵) being a digit (system variable ⎕D contains '0123456789')

⍵/⍨a  takes just the numeric part of the argument

(a/1,2</a)⊂  makes substrings of numbers only, starting at first number found
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pharo Smalltalk, 60

```
f:=[:s|(s splitOn:[:e|e isDigit not])reject:[:e|e isEmpty]]
```

Outputs:

```
f value:'abc123def456' -> OrderedCollection('123' '456')  
f value:'aitew034snk582:3c' -> OrderedCollection('034' '582' '3')  
f value:'as5493tax54\430-52@g9.fc' -> OrderedCollection('5493' '54' '430' '52' '9')  
f value:'sasprs]tore\"re\forz' -> OrderedCollection()
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 50 bytes

**Note that the TIO counts 48, that is because it doesn't count the global at the top**

```c
c;
void split(unsigned char *s, unsigned char **a) {
for(c=0;*s;s++)c=*s-48u>9?*s=0:c?:(*a++=s);*a=0;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZFdb4IwFIbv@RUnLEugqEEoi9qh@x/iBZaizbCQnrLP7LezDvVCFuJFb54@b9/0HD49cN49SMWrthDwjKaQ9ey4dm5QJfe3jJvPRvwhzpy3WhaATSUNeK1CeVCiAH7MNRCcwICQ3Ifvrqy1x9OQEWQYBD5PCU7pol0vNwTTcMU3K4/kQZCiz0huve4HAJxzU9GemmEPMfZVxzrQaKlM6blbcH32V8OIYcZ2XC8eEdwJ2AC7kl2mrOucKyyCUy6Vd31w2KQhtUJV1dybhxG1wf@WEWjm25013XzP51FciJImT@6YG11cacR7GFNUr8kiWsV8NBBfApjQZWzyj4RmGY3DaRK9HJazcjxIz0HMsdG4M7UWmWtPZif1dQn1m/T6L0y0z6CH/dC1PzSiu0Z816Ajhham1QpCuxmn@wU)

Significant improvement of [Coaumdio's algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21981/94093) which I would comment on, but the user hasn't been active since then.

The most notable difference is that it uses `unsigned char *` instead of `char *`. This is because the function signature is free, and it allows us to do unsigned arithmetic instead of `ctype`. This doesn't affect the test cases, but if we were to have a character with the high bit set, it would.

```c
for(c=0;*s;s++)
```

I moved the variable to a global variable with implicit int and initialized in the for loop. Saves 3 bytes.

Otherwise, this simply loops through `s` until it reaches the null terminator.

Now to explain this glorious hot garbage.

```c
c=*s-48u>9?*s=0:c?:(*a++=s);
```

Let's format it a little better, convert it to an if-else, and step through it.

Overview of the logic:

```c
if (*s - (unsigned)'0' > 9) { // c=*s-48u>9?
    c = *s = '\0';            //   *s=0
} else if (c != 0) {          // :c?
    c = c;                    //   // implicit: c
} else {                      // :
    c = (int)(*a++ = s);      //   (*a++ = s)
}                             // ;
```

```c
if (*s - (unsigned)'0' > 9) { // c=*s-48u>9?
```

Thanks to unsigned arithmetic, we can remove the `isdigit` call entirely.

Basically, what the subtraction does is an unsigned subtraction, with negatives being converted to really big positives.

So for example:

```c
' ' = 32 - 48 = -16 = 4294967280 (for a 32-bit int)
'0' = 48 - 48 = 0 = 0
'9' = 54 - 48 = 9 = 9
'A' = 65 - 48 = 17 = 17
```

As you can see, `'0'` to `'9'` will be turned into `0`-`9`, and anything else will be larger than that, so we can just check if the result of the subtraction is greater than 9.

```c
    c = *s = '\0';            //   *s=0
```

If it is not a digit, we will replace the contents of `*s` with a `'\0'` byte. The result of this assignment makes the ternary return 0, also assigning `c` to 0.

```c
} else if (c != 0) {          // :c?
    c = c;                    //   // implicit: c
```

If it *is* a digit and `c` is set, we set it to itself using [GCC's `?:` extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html), which evaluates to the condition itself for true if the middle of the ternary is left out.

```c
} else {                      // :
    c = (int)(*a++ = s);      //   (*a++ = s)
}                             // ;
```

Last, if it is a digit and `c` is not set, we will store `s` into `a` and advance it, and here is the disgusting part: We then use the result of that assignment to set `c` to a non-zero value...assigning an integer to a pointer.

```c
*a=0;
```

Finally, we `NULL` terminate `a` and return.

Answer (score -1):

**C# 66**

```
static char[] n(string s){return s.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray();}
```

Comment: This is not a valid solution, I don't think the OP wants you to split on the empty string ;)